# Infinite double potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, boundary-value-problem

So I'm having problems with the double infinite potential well given by

[image]

I have to use the fact that the potential well is symmetric about $x=0$. I have solved the Schrödinger equation in all the regions and end up with

$$\psi1=A\sin(k_1x)+B\cos(k_1x)$$
$$\psi2=Ce^{k_2x}+De^{-k_2x}$$
$$\psi3=E\sin(k_1x)+F\cos(k_1x)$$

where $k_1=\sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}}$ and $k_2=\sqrt{\frac{2m(v_0-E)}{\hbar^2}}$. I Use the symmetry argument and get $C=D$ which means $cosh$ for even and $sinh$ for odd wave functions. I'm really struggling to normalise the piecewise wave functions... I know that I'm meant to get $A\sin(k_1(a+b-x))$ but I'm not sure how. So if I know how to do that it may help me normalise the wave function. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: does [method of pertubation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory) work??

Comment: I'm positive I don't need to use any perturbation methods

Comment: use the continuity of the functions and their derivative at boundary of each region .... i.e. $\psi_1(a) = \psi_2(a)$ and $\psi_1'(a) = \psi_2'(a)$ and get rid of the constant like A, B, ... as much as possible. normalize it later ... by setting the integral from $-(a+b) \to (a+b)$. Ugh ... looks like awful lot of work to me.